# Python - stock price for different stocks plotting (without yfinance)

Tags: python, pandas, graphs

I have a dataset which contains a few stocks in a range of dates. [image: My data]

I searched in internet but most of the solutions gives solutions with `yfinance` and I'm not interested in that.
This data is imported from a csv file. Without using yfinance I would like to represent it graphically i.e. x-axis `day_date`, y axis `close_value` and different lines representing different stocks.
So far `ndaq.set_index("day_date", inplace=True)` I choose `day_date` to be an index and selected only `ndaq.loc[:, ['ticker_symbol','close_value','volume']]` to shrink the data. But the graph I have plots everything as one without distinguishing through different stock names.

Comment: seems like a pivot question; ndaq.pivot(index='day_date', columns='ticker_symbol').close_value.plot()

Comment: I like the R libraries [tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/) and [mmtable](https://ianmoran11.github.io/mmtable2/index.html) or gtable for stuff like this.

Comment: ndaq.pivot() worked perfectly :)